# How to implement DDMenu with storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, menu

I want to add slide menu to my iOS application. I found `DDMenuviewController` which is under **MIT** licence. I downloaded the code from GitHub. But they implemented this by programmatically.

My question is how to use `DDMenuviewcontroller` with storyboards.

Comment: you can give the specific nibs to your leftviewcontroller and rightviewcontrollers in did finish launching....

Comment: @Agent thanx for your reply. I want to use DMMenuviewcontroller on third screen. Now how can i instantiate DMMenuviewcontroller in did finish launch.

Comment: no issues load your first view by - (ViewController *)demoController {
 return [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}

- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {
 return [[UINavigationController alloc]
     initWithRootViewController:[self demoController]];
}

Comment: add right and left controllers and make ddmenu as your rootview and where u need to use just use clk method to be found in sample code...